# New generated PDF is not shown in webView using google docs viewer using android

Tags: android

The problem i got in showing PDF is that it will show the old PDF view as i have created new PDF in server. it is not refreshing it . sometimes it show the correct PDf and sometimes it shows the previous generated PDf. As i have deleted the previous Pdf from the server through coding and genrate new PDf through coding but still it shows the old PDF that is not available in webView.I have checked the server database the old file is deleted and new is generated and there is no issue generatin and deleting in server database but with web view or google docs. I have used clear cache , clear history in webview but still its not working.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mention that you have used clear cache and clear history it should work. It is strange that it's not working.

You can check one of the following and try:

1. first put the URL inside the your PC browser and check whether correct pdf is opening if there the proper pdf opening then inside the Mobile browser that pdf has to open.
2. Inside the mobile go to the setting - Application - Manage Application  - Go to your application from there unchecked all the option means(Force stop,clear data, clear cache) and now check once again.

Hope now it works. May be because the page it is stored inside the mobile browser cache that's why it giving such unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes it is working in the PC browser. The main thing i am creating an application in which user will generate PDF dynamically and that will be stored on the server database. From there i am showing the PDF n google docs viewer. And i am clearing the webview cache programically bt still it does not work, Sometimes it shows generated PDf file sometime it shos old PDF.

Comment: @user726633 Have you tried the second option. If possible can you please Uninstall and Install it again(Application Mobile). but your saying some times it showing the update some times not? This is because of the cache problem according to me. I am not sure.